# RegEx Extracting Domain Name

Tags: regex, regex-negation

How Do I Extract Domain Name Without backslash, I am Almost done.
https://regex101.com/r/g1Rtei/1

```
\w+\.[a-z]\w[a-z]\/
```

https://cartsyard.com/wp-login.php
http://www.regexcookbook.com/index.html or from /index.html#fragment.

i need domain name without backslash /

Comment: If you would, please post all the code relevant to the question *in the question itself* - don't hide it behind a link. You shouldn't tell potential helpers who would otherwise love to help that they have to navigate offsite just to have an idea of what you're working with. If the link breaks, the question could be rendered useless to future readers. Please edit your code into the question in a [MCVE], or the question might get closed, thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `?=` like this: `\w+\.[a-z]\w[a-z](?=\/)`.
Details at: https://regex101.com/r/g1Rtei/2

Comment: Thanks, Solved, BTW What Does ?= Means In Regex? Just To Clear The Concept.

Comment: It means "positive look ahead". Example: `abc(?=def)`, will get the "abc" follow by "def" (but "def" not in the matching result)!